# Adding explicit namespace attribute to particular xml tags

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

In a quick-and-dirty conversion from XML generated by one program (htlatex) to another (ArborText Editor), I need to replace all XML of the following form

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<mn>
....
</mn>
</math>
```

with

```
<m:math xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<m:mn xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
....
</m:mn>
</m:math>
```

Is there a cleaner *easy* way to achieve this rather than searching for tags `<math`, `<mn>` etc. and replacing them? Or can this be done via xslt?

Comment: Do you really need `m` namespace prefix declaration to be in every element instead of at the root level element only? This part to be clear : `xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"`

Comment: It seems so. Although, in my opinion, the xml files are equivalent, the target program (ArborText Editor) seems to accept only the second form. Defining the namespace prefix "m" at the root level of the document not help.

Comment: Your example data is extremely small. Are you saying that you need a namespace definition on *every element*, or just on `math` and `mn` elements?

Comment: I need a namespace definition on every nested element inside a `<math>...</math>` element.

Comment: The two documents *are* semantically equivalent, and if your target application understands one but not the other, then it doesn't know how to parse XML. I doubt XSLT is the tool to solve this problem, because you have no control over the exact lexical representation an XSLT processor will choose for the output (although you *might* find one that under certain circumstances will oblige).

Comment: @JohnB This can be done using XSLT if the expected result is rather like this (no repeated ns prefix declaration at the descendant level) : `<m:math xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<m:mn>
....
</m:mn>
</m:math>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I am going to use regex to this! If you are afraid They might get you, stop reading now.

---

Because this is a very limited kind of problem, I believe using an XML parser to find the things we want to change and then using regex is ok here. We are not trying to parse anything with the regex, just replacing simple text patterns.

I used [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) to find all the `math` nodes, grabber their XML as a string, replaced the namespaces and put the XML back, which makes XML::Twig parse the altered string. If the regex manipulation broke something to the extend that it's invalid, we will notice here because the parsing will fail.

Of course this asumes there are no other namespaces inside the `math` elements.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = <<XML;
<container>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<mn>
<foo>asdf</foo>
<bar>fdsa</bar>
</mn>
</math>
</container>
XML

my $t = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => {
        math => sub {
            my $new_xml = $_->outer_xml;
            $new_xml =~ s{ xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"}{};
            $new_xml =~ s{<([a-zA-Z]+)}{<m:$1 xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"}g;
            $new_xml =~ s{</}{</m:}g;

            $_->set_outer_xml($new_xml);
        },
    }
);
$t->parse($xml);
$t->print;
```

Output contains the namespace in each element starting from `math`.

```
<container>
  <m:math xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <m:mn xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
      <m:foo xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">asdf</m:foo>
      <m:bar xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">fdsa</m:bar>
    </m:mn>
  </m:math>
</container>
```

I verified that it works for more deeply nested structures and multiple `math` elements.